# Need help on simple C command line argument

Tags: c, command-line

I don't really know how to explain this but here's my problem:

I am trying to make my program accept command line arguments and then run a program via. the Linux command line (CentOS 6).

Heres the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I am trying to run a Linux program, here's the code:

```
system("nmap -sT -p 19 1.1.1.* -oG - | grep 19/open > temp");
```

I want to replace '1.1.1.*' with the first argument I input into my C program, Ex:

```
system("nmap -sT -p 19 ", (argv[1]) "-oG - | grep 19/open > temp");
```

I have tried multiple ways and none seemed to work.

To sum it up, i'm trying to take the  first argument I input into my program and use it in replace of the '1.1.1.*' in the system function. I have no idea on how to do this, I'm new to C programming. Thank you all replies are appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [sprintf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sprintf/).  Use `sprintf` to combine `argv[1]` and the command you want to run, and then store the output to a variable and pass that variable to system like this:  `char* a = sprintf("stuff %s", argv[1]); system(a);`

Comment: Both `sprintf` and `strcat` are asking for buffer overruns (especially when accepting user input for one part of the constructed string) unless you keep careful track of the length of the result. And since you *are* going to be keeping track you can (and should!) use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: @dmckee You are correct, `snprintf` is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is the safest way to do this, this is a simple example without any checking of `argc` etc...:

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char buf[200] ;
    char str1[] = "nmap -sT -p 19  ";
    char str2[] = " -oG - | grep 19/open > temp";

    snprintf(buf, 200, "%s%s%s", str1, argv[1], str2);
    printf( "%s\n", buf ) ;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following syntax to accept command line arguments in Linux.
  ./program arg1 arg2